# How to use class on primary menu ul instead of div in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, menu, html-lists

I used this php coding in wordpress to get primary menu.

```
<?php

  wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu' => 'Top menu',
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'depth' => 2,
    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
  ));

?>
```

This is the output in preview.

```
<div class="nav navbar-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"> NEWS  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FUNNY PICTURES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">FUNNY VIDEOS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">GOVERMENT JOBS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">HEALTH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">BEST SHOPING DEAL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This should work like below, not like above. Please explain what the change is need to made in php code.

```
<div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#"> NEWS  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What are "FUNNY PICTURES" & others and what is "test"?

Comment: I'm sure the people here can help you with that: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry, i am using this website first time so extra content there which is not visible.  This is the output of above code in wordpress.

Comment: <div  class="nav navbar-nav">
<ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"> NEWS  <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FUNNY PICTURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FUNNY VIDEOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">GOVERMENT JOBS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HEALTH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BEST SHOPING DEAL</a></li>
      </ul>

</div>

Comment: I want to use this class "nav navbar-nav" on ul instead of div, Currently it is showing on div instead of ul

Comment: If you want to add css styles to this ul, you can access it by: ".nav.navbar-nav ul"

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) which states clearly all the things you need .

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

i didn't clearly understand your question but from what i have understood you may use **container class** to add class to the div folder and **menu_class** add class name to **ul** element .